# arithmetics between large primitive numeric types : can I save the overflow?

Tags: c++, c, math, primitive, primitive-types

*disclaimer: I know, unsigned integers are primitive numeric types but they don't technically overflow, I'm using the term "overflow" for all the primitive numeric types in general here.*

in C or C++, according to the standard or to a particular implementation, there are primitive numeric types where given an arithmetic operation, even if this operation could possibly overflow, I can save the result + plus the part that overflows ?

Even if this sounds strange, my idea is that the registers on modern CPUs are usually much larger than a 32 bit `float` or a 64 bit `uint64_t`, so there is the potential to actually control the overflow and store it somewhere.

Comment: are you sure you really mean [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) types? not scalar types?

Comment: @BryanChen damn acronyms, there is always someone somewhere else that interprets stuff differently ! Ok, I mean `int`, `unsigned int` and `float` or `double` basically, all the primitive types. Plus the variations like `short` and `long`.

Comment: There aren't even PODs in C...

Comment: well, they are defined by standard, so there should only be one correct definition per standard

Comment: *primitive numeric types* is probably a more accurate term

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks, now I fixed that so we are both on the same page

Comment: _'so there is the potential to actually control the overflow and store it somewhere'_ provide a sample what you mean to clarify please.

Comment: @g-makulik there are registers that are 128 bit or 256 bit wide, no primitive numeric type that I know is more than 64 bit wide.

Comment: Then I think there's no way to implement support for such big numeric primitives just using standard c++/c without interfacing explicitly at assembly language level.

Comment: @g-makulik: There certainly is: "magic" functions, called *intrinsics*, that appear to be part of the library but actually have special translation in the compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt Are those intrinsics a portable feature? Otherwise I'd prefer to provide my own class interfaces for such, and optimize the implementation details for the platforms needed to be supported.

Comment: @g-makulik: Definitely YMMV.  For example, gcc ports try to use the same name for the same intrinsic on all platforms, where available.  And gcc vs Visual C++ don't even share the same name on the same platform.  The function call syntax itself is of course very portable, and typically you can provide a definition which a compiler that recognizes the intrinsic will ignore in favor of its built-in special translation.

Comment: @BenVoigt But THX for the insight anyway LANTED! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the registers are not "usually much larger than a 64 bit `uint64_t`".

There's an overflow flag, and for a limited number of operations (addition and subtraction), pairing this single additional bit with the result is enough to capture the entire range of outcomes.

But in general, you'd need to cast to a larger type (potentially implemented in software) to handle results that overflow the type of your input.

Any operations that do this sort of thing (for example some 32-bit processors had a 32x32 => 32 high, 32 low wide multiply instruction) will be provided by your compiler as intrinsic functions, or via inline assembly.

look, I found a 64-bit version of that, named [Multiply128](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802931.aspx)  and [the matching `__mul128` instrinsic available in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/82cxdw50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @user2485710: An AVX register isn't a single 256-bit quantity, it acts more like an array of disconnected smaller registers.

Comment: @user2485710: I don't believe AVX has 256-bit scalar maths.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I can't believe than among SSE, MMX and AVX there is nothing for scalar math with a check on the overflow ...

Comment: @user2485710: A "check" on the overflow is quite different from capturing the magnitude of overflow.  In most instructions, it's just a simple overflowed-vs-not flag, 1 bit.  In other instructions, overflow is detected and handled by clamping (the SSE family of instructions definitely has that ability)

Answer (score 2):

See @Ben Voigt about larger registers.

There really may only be an overflow bit that *could* help you.

Another approach, without resorting to wider integers, is to test overflow yourself:

```
unsigned a,b,sum;
sum = a + b;
if (sum < a) {
  OverflowDetected();  // mathematical result is `sum` + UINT_MAX + 1
}
```

Similar approach for `int`.
The following likely may be simplified - just don't have it at hand.

[Edit]
My below apporach has potentila UB.  For a better way to detect `int` overflow, see [Simpler method to detect int overflow](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/simpler-method-to-detect-int-overflow/37178?noredirect=1#37178)

```
int a,b,sum;
sum = a + b;
// out-of-range only possible when the signs are the same.
if ((a < 0) == (b < 0)) {
  if (a < 0) {
    if (sum > b) UnderflowDetected();
  }
  else {
    if (sum < b) OverflowDetected();
  }
```

Comment: Wow, `bool f(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return a + b < a; }` is optimized by the GNU compiler to `addl %edi, %esi; setb %al; ret`. How awesome is that?

Answer (score 1):

For floating point type, you can actually 'control' the overflow on x86 platform. With these functions ["_control87, _controlfp, __control87_2"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9st43tcf.aspx), you can Gets and sets the floating-point control word. By default, the run-time libraries mask all floating-point exceptions; you can unmask them in your code, so when a overflow occurs, you'll get an exception. However, the code we write today, all assume that the floating point exceptions are masked, so if you unmask them, you'll encounter some problem.

You can use these [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9st43tcf.aspx) to get the status word.

Comment: **If** you are using a Microsoft compiler on an x86 platform.

Comment: @Oli: The names may vary, but all compilers for x86 should provide this.

Answer (score 1):

For floating point types the results are well defined by the hardware, and you're not going to be able to get much control without working around C/C++.

For integer types smaller than `int`, they will be upsized to an `int` by any arithmetic operation. You will probably be able to detect overflow before you coerce the result back into the smaller type.

For addition and subtraction you can detect overflow by comparing the result to the inputs. Adding two positive integers will always yield a result larger than either of the inputs, unless there was overflow.

Comment: what do you mean with "probably be able to detect overflow" ? How ?

Comment: @user2485710 by looking at the result to see if it's larger than the smaller type can hold. I can only think of one case where that wouldn't catch every overflow - `unsigned short * unsigned short`.